# Finding integer solutions of a function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider the function
$f(x)=x^3 -8x^2 +20x -13$
The question tells us to find out the number of integers x for which f(x) is a prime number. First method I tried was obviously substitution which gives us the integers we want, but it is an unreliable and time taking method. Thus, my next idea was shifting the origin to some prime number which would be the value of f(x) but I am confused how to proceed. Any little help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint: $f(x)=(x-1)(x^2-7x+13)$.

Comment: Hello sir, I factorised it. Got the same equation. Then equated it with prime numbers too, but how to know how many primes do exist, because otherwise, we will keep shifting the origin to find integral solutions to the equation. SOrry for any negligence. Thanks

Comment: @SanikaKhadkikar If a prime number is written as a product of two integers, then one of those integers must be 1 or -1.  Hence, if $f(x)$ is prime, then $x-1=\pm1$ or $x^2-7x+13=\pm1$.  Can you finish the argument from there?

Comment: Thanks! yes! @matthewconroy